# wp8 Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync can't get the new folder under Assets

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I created new folders under assets, and used the following code to get the new folder
but failed by : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

var folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\AnimalImages");

not sure that's why

Answer (score 4):

You should use `await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(...)`

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\Assets\AnimalImages");
```